# cakephp require vendor file interferes with loading model and shows error

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three controllers -

> 1. WebServices Controller
> 2. Bugs Controller
> 3. Project Controller

```
**WebservicesController.php**

App::import('Vendor','nusoap');

App::import('Vendor','autotask');

class WebservicesController extends AppController {
}

**BugsController.php**

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
App::import('Controller', 'Webservices');

class BugsController extends AppController {   
    public $uses = array('Bug','Project');

    public function edit($id = null) {    
    $project_name = $this->Project->get_project_name_by_id($this->request-    >query['pid']);

    }
```

}

**autotask.php**

require "autotaskwrapper.php"; --> this is another class I need to include. So far this seems to be the issue. Is it because I am using "require" instead of "App::import". If that's the case how can I use App::import in a vendor class

If I remove this  App::import('Vendor','autotask'); from the Webservices controller, everything works fine. If I include it says -

```
   Call to undefined method Project::get_project_name_by_id()
```

Comment: what is the version of cake?

Comment: I think this might help [App::import()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#app-import). And why are you importing one controller into another?

Comment: adding App::import('Vendor','autotaskwrapper'); to autotask.php shows the above error.

Comment: And where does it say that? This error message is straightforward, undefined method in `Project` model.

Comment: When I try to call the edit method in bugs controller, the method in the Projetc model is very much existing. As soon as I remove the App:import line from the webservices controller, it works.

Comment: Again, why are you importing one controller into another one?

Comment: Is it bad practice? I have a lot of methods in that controller that I will need to use throughout the site.

Comment: You need to first understand MVC and read cake documentation. You should create [Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#components) for that purpose.

Comment: This is my first cakephp project. Can you create custom components?

Comment: Yes and you can use power of AppControler, place some logic in there too, since all controllers extend it.

Comment: this is really getting on my nerves. I created a component
App::import('Vendor','autotask');
class WebservicesComponent extends Component  {
}

autotask.php
App::import('Vendor','autotaskwrapper'); --> This line just breaks it .. it doesn't load my Project model anymore